# azure dns record sets through kusto query

Tags: azure, dns, kql, azure-resource-graph

I am trying to find some reference for kusto queries for azure. In particular, I would like to find out how to query resources such as dns record sets.
I am able, through a trial and error approach to extract for example dns zones, by using the following code:

```
query = "Resources " \
        "| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Network/dnszones' "
```

but I'm stuck when dealing with record sets, because, based on the [doc reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/record-sets/list-all-by-dns-zone) it should be something like this:

```
query = "Resources " \
        "| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Network/dnszones/{zone_name}/all' "
```

but it doesn't work. I know this is not the proper reference to follow, because it's for rest api, so if anyone could help with the correct one, it'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

There may be thousands of record sets in public and private zones  and some limits apply for them.

[DNS Zones and Records overview - Azure DNS | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records#limits)

> **Note.** The most granular element that you can see metrics for is a DNS zone. ***You currently can't see metrics for individual resource
> records within a zone*** but can see its count and maximum value.

I have tried to reproduce the same:
below is just DNS Zones i too could get.

[image]

Then tried to get its properties which has cont of record sets ,their maximum count but did not give entire record set values itself.

**Query:**

```
resources 
        | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Network/dnszones' 
        | project id, name, type, properties
        |  order by name asc
```

[image]

When tried to query for record sets it shows invalidQuesry error as below:

[image]

Getting all those record sets can be done through azure rest api or azure powershell.

See this [Azure Resource Graph Query Private DNS zones - get all DNS records - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71259742/azure-resource-graph-query-private-dns-zones-get-all-dns-records)

You can raise a [***support request***](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/newsupportrequest) or feature request for the same.